# PHP session_start returns false, $_SESSION variables are not persistent

Tags: php, html, session, session-cookies, session-variables

Let me start by saying that I'm relatively new to PHP, so apologies if this seems trivial. Also, apologies if a similar scenario has already been answered, but I couldn't seem to find any solutions that worked for me by browsing through the similar questions.

I am trying to set up a login page for my website, which I aim to use $_SESSION variables to store the users login credentials once they have logged in. However, I can't find a way to make the $_SESSION variables persist through to other pages, or even stay when the web page has been refreshed.

It should be noted that:

Whenever I try to call session_start(), it always returns false. I call it at the very start of my php code, without any white space before it.

Whenever I call session_status, it always returns 1. This happens regardless of wherever it is called in the php code.

Whenever I call session_id, it always returns null. Again, this happens regardless of wherever it is called in the php code.

The code is being ran on SiteGround's web hosting services. I haven't tested it locally as I am relatively new to php and I'm not quite confident on how to host php files locally.

I have tested this both on; my windows PC using chrome, and my iPhone using Safari. Both have the same issues.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated as something which would seem rather trivial has been driving me crazy for the past couple of days.

*EDIT*

The following code is what I'm using to test the issues.

```
<?php
if (session_start())
{
    echo '<script>console.log("YES"); </script>';
} else {
    echo '<script>console.log("NO"); </script>';
}

$_SESSION["test"] = "YEET";
echo '<script>console.log("'.$_SESSION["test"].'"); </script>'; // prints YEET
?>


<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['test']))
{
    echo '<script>console.log("'.$_SESSION["test"].'"); </script>';
} else {
    echo '<script>console.log("NEET"); </script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: For local PHP testing you can use WAMP or XAMP, To help you better with your code issue, post your code in your question

Comment: I've updated my question to include a snippet of my code.

Comment: Dont place your session_start in an if statement

Comment: And im not 100% sure but, setting session variables needs to be done for any output like echo

Comment: This was to test if it was returning true or false, as that had been recommended in a similar question. Removing it from the if statement will still produce the same issues.

Comment: You also tried removing the echo before session write

Comment: Yes, yet still no differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I found the solution.

Even though SiteGround (my host) had set the session.save_path to be /tmp, I still had to write a custom php.ini file with this file path. This has since resolved the issue, and it was made clear that the session.save_path was the issue once I set the php.ini file to display both errors and startup errors.